# filter html text Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i want to filter this text:

```
<h2><u>Title</u></h2>
<p><strong>text</strong> text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1454" src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" alt="alttext" width="355" height="355" /></p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h3><u>h3 tag</u><strong><u>text</u></strong></h3>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/video" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
<h4><u>text</u></h4>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
<h4>text</h4>
<p>text</p>
```

Here is my fillter

```
app.filter('to_trusted',  function($sce){
        return function(text) { 
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
});
```

html file:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content | to_trusted"></div>
```

i filter the text but i cant get image link, i can see only youtube video

```
GET file://www.domain.com/image.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: may be you are not getting proper path

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the image url is not going through because 'http' is deemed as unsafe by $sanitize.  See the following default whitelist as found in the angular source code (sanitizeUri.js):

```
imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*((https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\/)/;
```

You could add 'http' to `ngSrcSanitizationWhitelist`, however I'm not too sure of the security implications of doing so.  If possible, having the image transfer via 'https' would be preferable.

See the following sources for more information: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider